# why runing python script from PHP executes in background?

Tags: php, python

I would like to open a CMD shell in windows containing a python script runing, i'm using python 2.7 and PHP using WAMP server i tried the code below in a PHP script :

```
exec('C:\Python27\python.exe C:\wamp64\www\test.py');
```

Without success it runs python in the background, I want to see the shell, I used 2>&1 it didn't work either, I tried `exec_shell()` and `system()` but couldn't figure it out.
any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php   exec doesn't do output. it can RETURN the last line of output, or put all of the output in an optional argument you provide.

Comment: how can i show the script running in console then ?

Comment: Go read that page. it clearly tells you what your option is in that case.

Comment: found nothing useful for my case

Comment: `If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function. `

Comment: I don't want the data back to the browser, i need it in the console when running, just like i'm running the Python script without calling it from PHP.

Comment: if you're running this on the command line, the your terminal IS "the browser".